# How do I pass an array of strings as a functions own argument? Compiler says it doesn't work

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a homework problem that says to create a function that takes an array of strings as its argument and prints out a greeting to each of your friends.

The first step was to create an array that contains the names of some of my friends and that's what I have here:

```
let friendsOfMine = ["Philip", "Sal", "June"]

func greetFriends(friendsOfMine) {
    for (index, friend) in  friendsOfMine.enumerated() {
        print("Hello \(friend)")
    }
}

greetFriends(friendsOfMine)
```

When I try to run, I get the error:

> exit status 1
>   main.swift:34:19: error: unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_' func

My task is to specifically:

> Use a for-loop to accomplish this task.

I've tried using "_" to solve but it doesn't work. 
I've tried putting the values(strings) of my array inside the functions parameter as an argument and it still doesn't work.

I expect the output to be:

```
Hello Philip
Hello Sal
Hello June
```

Comment: You don't need enumerated

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `greetFriends` doesn't have the correct syntax for its parameter.

You want something like:

```
func greetFriends(_ friends: [String]) {
    for (index, friend) in  friends.enumerated() {
        print("Hello \(friend)")
    }
}
```

You should review the [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) chapter of the Swift book (as well as the rest of the book).

Comment: index is not used

Comment: @ielyamani No, it's not but that's not relevant to the question.